# Keep unmounted partitions from showing up in dock

Tags: boot, mount

I have one internal SSD disk with 4 partitions that I keep around for recovery purposes. Right now, on 22.04.3, all these partitions show up in the `Dock` at boot time but are not mounted. The icons can not be removed from the `Dock` using the conventional method of right-clicking on the icon and getting a remove action. Is there any way of preventing these partition icons from being displayed? I don't mind the partitions showing up in `/dev`.

Comment: @user68186 This does the job perfectly. I sis not know that the disk utility existed. I find good documentation on the Gnome utilities to be hard to find. If you make tIf you make your response an answer, I can accept it.

Comment: I am voting to close this question as a duplicate of the linked old question unless the accepted answer to that question does not have something your question needs. Feel free to up vote the accepted answer to the old question.